Setting a prop to never vs setting a prop to undefined
I am trying to make a function that can receive some args together or none of them.
I tried this:
type AllOrNone<T> = Required<T> | Partial<Record<keyof T, never>>;
type BaseArgs = {a: string}
type Group = {b: number; c: number}

type FooArgs = BaseArgs & AllOrNone<Group>;
declare function foo(arg: FooArgs)

foo({
  a: 's',
  b: 5
})

And I get this error:
Argument of type '{ a: string; b: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FooArgs'.
  Type '{ a: string; b: number; }' is not assignable to type 'BaseArgs & Partial<Record<keyof Group, never>>'.
    Type '{ a: string; b: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Record<keyof Group, never>>'.
      Types of property 'b' are incompatible.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)

Which works but is not very informative for the user on what the type should be. I would expect, as b was passed with a number, that it will say that c is missing. Changing never to undefined (i.e. type AllOrNone<T> = Required<T> | Partial<Record<keyof T, undefined>>;) fixes this problem but I'm not sure as to why using never doesn't show the same error.

not typescript expert at all, but from what I see here https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-never you are misunderstanding the idea - never means you don't expect value at all. What probably happens is before the existence of c is checked, you get the type error.

I can't reproduce that error. Seems to be working as expected.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! This doesn't seem to be a [mre]; the error you're mentioning doesn't appear when others look at your code in their own IDEs (and note that declare function foo(arg: FooArgs) is missing a return type annotation, so it's invalid... have you checked this in an IDE?). Please [edit] to make a [mre] or this question risks being closed as needing debugging details. Note that for normal compiler options, Partial<Record<keyof T, never>> and Partial<Record<keyof T, undefined>> are equivalent types, so I'd be surprised to see a difference.
